# MBR status confusion

Tags: mbr

> **EB** 58 90 6D 6B 64 6F 73 66 73 00 00 02 08 20 00 02 00 00 00 00 F8 00
>   00 3E 00 83 00 00 00 00 00 94 88 7E 00 98 1F 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
>   00 00 01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 29 A9 38
>   B1 34 57 61 76 65 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20 20 20 0E 1F
>   BE 77 7C AC 22 C0 74 0B 56 B4 0E BB 07 00 CD 10 5E EB F0 32 E4 CD 16
>   CD 19 EB FE 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 6E 6F 74 20 61 20 62 6F 6F 74 61
>   62 6C 65 20 64 69 73 6B 2E 20 20 50 6C 65 61 73 65 20 69 6E 73 65 72
>   74 20 61 20 62 6F 6F 74 61 62 6C 65 20 66 6C 6F 70 70 79 20 61 6E 64
>   0D 0A 70 72 65 73 73 20 61 6E 79 20 6B 65 79 20 74 6F 20 74 72 79 20
>   61 67 61 69 6E 20 2E 2E 2E 20 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 55 AA

Learning disk records, this is my USB MBR record viewed by bless on ubuntu formatted with disk utility as MBR table and FAT partition, referring to this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning) of first record

> status (0x80 = bootable (active), 0x00 = non-bootable, other = invalid
>   )

but my MBR shows first offset as `EB`. ( The first byte )

**What**'s this record stands for ? also, can you provide me with good tables/images tutorials for MBR and other disks' records :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the **master boot record** with the **partition table**.

The Wikipedia page about [master boot records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) you linked to explains the layout in detail:

- The first `440` bytes form the **code area**, which contains the boot loader.

  The boot loader is a tiny program that can get called by the BIOS.
- The next `6` bytes are entirely **optional**.

  They may contain a disk signature (usually `4` bytes) and (usually `2`) trailing `00` bytes.
- Only the next `64` bytes –  four `16`-byte entries for each of the four possible primary partitions – form the **partition table**.
- The last two bytes are always `55 AA`, the **MBR signature**.

In your example, the partition table consists entirely of `00` bytes, which means that your device contains no partitions.